# Firebase functions for all write operations

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

- **I have** a something like a social media application with complex write operations for example a follow request.
- The **Firestore rules** are so written that no one can write something to my database.
- **Right now** if a someone wants to follow a user, the client invokes a cloud functions with a uid argument, the cloud function is then executing a transaction with serval write operations.
- **I did this because** of the advantage to modify the transactions anytime so there is no client update needed.

**So my question:** Is it bad to use Cloud Functions for all write operations in my app and did I missed a disadvantage of this method?

Comment: If you are okay with writing those cloud functions no, there is no problem at all. What made you think that it has a disadvantage?

Comment: Because I've never seen anyone that used this method and I thinks it's not really desired by the firebase developers.

Comment: Because I personally think it's hard to write cloud functions, and basically also writing code to trigger them is more work than just forcing client to update and writing good old Java code)

Comment: But the problem by forcing client updates is that you need to deactivate features for those who don't get the updates, otherwise you would have inconsistency in your database.

Comment: That's right, but it's both more expensive and harder to write it with the method you use so if you're going to push a lots of updates yes, it could be better to use cloud functions

Comment: Why do you write so complex things? Do you really need to lock down ALL of your database? Why not simply make a one-to-one follow relationship with composite key (like `followerUid_followingUid`) inside a `following` collection and let users write in that collection ? And just invoque a cloud function to aggregate the follower count? If i'm a user, I don't want to wait 3 sec to have my UI updated when I follow someone...

Comment: I only lock down any write access to the database. When a user follows someone the UI will be instantly refreshed with the expected values. The function is running on the server so there is no need for the client to wait. But thanks, I will think about it.

Comment: Yeah with the optimistic UI approach.. but cloud function have some delay so.. whatever. I'm just telling you that using CF for this kind of tasks is just overkill. You could use CF for aggregation, some complex logic, some image transformation you know.. but the example in your post is just overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it bad to use Cloud Functions for all write operations in my app?

This is not bad by definition, but it's also not good by definition. It all depends on both your use-case and your implementation.

A few things to consider:

- The security rules for your data mutators are now essentially encoded in your Cloud Functions. So your Cloud Functions secured? Are you certain that only authorized users can call them?
- Did you consider letting your clients write their "follow this user" request to a special "client-requests" collection in Cloud Firestore? You could have Cloud Functions monitor writes to that collection, which would has its advantags.
- For example: since the clients write to Firestore in this scenario, their write operations will not fail when they're offline, but instead be sent to the server (and processed there) when they're back online. In your current scenario you'd have to implement such retry-logic yourself.

Comment: Yes, my functions are so far secured that only authenticated users can execute them. I did this with the predefined functions.https.onCall. Also I will definitely think about the idea with the requests collection. Thank you very much for your reply.